# Excel - CountIfs using column header and value from other column as criteria?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I am trying to produce a countifs formula to put in a cell on sheet 1, that will count the number of entries for ID 'A' on sheet 2.

But also i need to add a criteria to say only count the entries where the date in the column header on sheet 2 matches the date in the column header on sheet 1.

Sheet1

```
ID        01/01/2016          
A             1 (Formula goes here)               
B             0 (Formula goes here)             
C             1 (Formula goes here)             
D             1 (Formula goes here)             


Sheet2
ID        01/01/2016      
A         1pm - 2pm       
B                         
C         1pm - 2pm        
D         1pm - 2pm
```

I am really struggling to get this to work. so far i have put together this, but it doesn't have the criteria for the dates.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Data!$A$2:$A$1000=$A2)*(Data!$D$2:D$1000="$D$1"))
```

Please can somemone show me where i am going wrong?

Comment: You said you want to `countif` but you used `sumproduct`. You also mentioned two sheet but you used only one sheet `Data` in formula. So how it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something closer to,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($F$2:$K$9<>"")*($F$1:$K$1=$B$1)*($E$2:$E$9=$A2))
```

I've put everything on one worksheet but you should have no trouble splitting it off to Sheet2.

[image: Sumproduct_countifs]

Comment: I'm not sure why, but this doesn't seem to be working for me when i reference a second sheet =SUMPRODUCT((Data!$D$2:$NE$100<>"")*(Data!$D$1:$NE$1=F$10)*(Data!$A$2:$A$100=$A11))

Comment: There is something funny about your $A11 at the end; seems like unicode characters. In any event, see [sumproduct_countifs.xlsx](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/sumproduct_countifs.xlsx)

Comment: Thanks changed my cell ref from A11 to something else, seemed to do the trick

Comment: just realized that if i have a date in my cell which is concatenated i.e. =Concatenate(A1,A2,A3) which produces 07/01/2016 then this won't work with the formula you provided. Instead, it will only work if i have the date as a static value. Is there a way i can get this to work with concatenated values?